# Compare current date with table data?

Tags: date, datetime, hana

How can I compare current date with stored date in SAP HANA?

When I am using `dateFrom > CURRENT_DATE` in where clause it gives following error:

> CURRENT_DATE is reserved SQL keyword and cannot be used

`dateFrom` is of type UTCTimestamp.

Comment: To use reserved words, place backticks ( ` ) around the word.

Comment: @Tim: not in standard SQL (and I believe HANA complies with that). Reserved keywords need to be quoted using double quotes `"`

Comment: According to [the manual](http://help.sap.com/hana_one/html/sql_function_current_date.html) this should work just fine. Can you show use the complete query?

Answer (score 1):

First check the type of field, if is char, you need to convert this to DATE content, using TO_DATE(YOUR FIELD, MASK),

Then you can use NOW(), to get the current time and date from server.